# Changing Android Activity Base Class

Tags: android, android-activity, overriding, android-anr-dialog

I want to use [anr-watchdog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog) in a local repository of apps. Assume that I have for example 1000 apps (apk + src) and I want all of them to initialize the anr-watchdog in their main thread. All the things I need is a static method call in one of the activities of the app.

Basically I have tried to change the source codes of these apps but the structure of the projects are very different and some sources where incomplete so the build process is almost impossible.

I am looking for a way to override the activity base class for example in the firmware of the emulator or any simpler ways that I don't know.

Any idea to solve this???

TG.